# C++ Regex not matching adjacent groups?

Tags: c++, regex

I have a line that looks like the following in a file:

```
Location### Location### #
```

Where Location is a string representing a city where spaces are +'s(Such as "St.+Louis,+MO")
And the #'s are numeric digits.  I am trying to capture the locations as well as the digits (which represent unique node IDs in this network topology file) with the following regex pattern:

```
START "([A-Za-z,+.]+)([0-9]+)" SPACE "([A-Za-z,+.]+)([0-9]+)" SPACE "([0-9.]+)" MAYSPACE END
```

Using the C++ regex library (on Ubuntu Linux).  The macros are properly defined to match but not capture spaces (MAYSPACE matches 0 or more whitespace characters).

The problem that I'm encountering is that the groups for the numbers are completely empty!  If I put this regex into sed:

```
sed -rn 's/^([A-Za-z.+,]+)([0-9]+)/\1 \2/p' rocketfuel/weights/6461/latencies.intra
```

It works exactly as expected and captures both the city name and the node ID!  Furthermore, if I try the following match instead:

```
START "([A-Za-z,+.]+).([0-9]+)" SPACE "([A-Za-z,+.]+).([0-9]+)" SPACE "([0-9.]+)" MAYSPACE END
```

The node IDs will be captured, but are obviously missing the first digit!  I have tried putting the \B non-word-boundary anchor in there and had no luck...

Has anyone else ever encountered this issue with non-matching adjacent groups?  Does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix it?  It seems to be a bug with the actual C++ library...

I'm trying to avoid Boost or other external libraries so for now I'm going to use sed to add a space in between the location and node ID since I can parse everything just fine then.

Comment: Remember that most compiler still doesn't fully implement the C++11 features. GCC, for instance, doesn't support more than `regex_math` so you can't use e.g. `regex_search`, and that's in version 4.7. The support for regexes in GCC 4.6 (which is standard in Ubuntu 12.04) is probably even less complete.

Comment: I'm confused if you are actually using regular expressions. Boost implements regex for Unbutu I think. And I think that any C++0.x TR1 should also. Most of the implementations of C++ TR1 use Boos anyway I think.

Comment: Boost does the modern FULL implementation of Perl by default. Nothing wrong with that! Redistribution is usually a light weight dll or static lib. Most of the implementation is compiled as macro template classes, so that should be no problem.